# Nested context.executeQueryAsync with Deferred

Tags: javascript, arrays, sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-jsom

How can I use nested context.executeQueryAsync with Deferred? Below is my code and I will explain what exactly I am looking for:

**Code**

```
function getValues() {
    var dfd = $.Deferred(function () {

        context.executeQueryAsync(function () {
            var navigationItem = [];

            // First Loop
            while (termEnumerator.moveNext()) {

                // Push Parent Terms in navigationItem array
                navigationItem.push({ "name": ""});

                // Get Sub Terms
                context.executeQueryAsync(function () {
                    // Second Loop
                    while (termsEnum.moveNext()) {
                       // Push Sub Terms in navigationItem array
                        navigationItem.push({ "name": ""});
                    }
                }, function (sender, args) {
                    console.log(args.get_message());
                });
            }

            dfd.resolve(navigationItem);

        }, function (sender, args) {
            console.log(args.get_message());
            dfd.reject(args.get_message());
        });
    });
    return dfd.promise();
}
```

Basically I am trying to fetch Taxonomy (Terms & it's sub terms) in SharePoint Online using above code structure. Initially I have created an array named `navigationItem` and iterating through all the terms.

During iteration, first of all, I am pushing terms into this array and along with this, I am also getting it's sub terms if any and pushing it into the same array.

I want that code doesn't execute further until second loop completes it's execution. So that I will have final array while returning it to another function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want that code doesn't execute further until second loop completes
>   it's execution. So that I will have final array while returning it to
>   another function.

In this case, you need to have a defer for each executeQueryAsync.

Then, you need a create an overall defer to wait all of the async methods finished.

Here is the sample code for your reference:

```
(function ($) {
    function executeQueryAsync(succeededCallback, failedCallback)
    {
        var period = Math.random() * 10000;

        setTimeout(function () {
            succeededCallback();
        }, period);

    }

    function forEachAsync(items, funcAsync, callback)
    {
        var count = 0;

        var total = $.Deferred();

        function increment()
        {
            count++;

            if(count == items.length)
            {
                total.resolve();
            }
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
        {
            (function exec(item) {
                var deferred = $.Deferred(function (defer) {
                    funcAsync(function () {
                        callback();
                        defer.resolve();
                    });
                });

                deferred.done(function () {
                    increment();
                });
            })(items[i]);
        }

        return total.promise();
    }

    var promise = forEachAsync([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], executeQueryAsync, function () {
        console.log('call back executing + ' + Date.now());
    });

    promise.done(function () {
        console.log("promise done");
    });
})(jQuery);
```

[image]